# Commutation of Tensor Products as operators

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, quantum-computation

Suppose I have unitary operators $$A: \mathbb{C}^{2^k} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2^k}$$
$$B: \mathbb{C}^{2^j} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2^j}$$

For some $k,j \in \mathbb{Z}, j,k \ge 0$. How do  show that

$$ A \otimes I_{2^j} \circ I_{2^k}  \otimes B = I_{2^k}  \otimes B \circ  A \otimes I_{2^j} $$

### Work So Far:

A "proof by thought experiment" is as follows, $A$, $B$ can be different quantum operators operating on different sets of Qubits. Then assuming a system of $k+j$  Qubits (Of which we apply $A$ to the first $k$ Qubits and $B$ to the other group simultaneously) the entire operator can be represented as either

$$ A \otimes I_{2^j} \circ I_{2^k}  \otimes B$$

or

$$ I_{2^k}  \otimes B \circ  A \otimes I_{2^j} $$

Depending on which you evaluate first. But since we know those operators are on disjoint sets of Qubits, the order SHOULD not matter. So we conclude that:

$$ A \otimes I_{2^j} \circ I_{2^k}  \otimes B = I_{2^k}  \otimes B \circ  A \otimes I_{2^j} $$

But this proof now rests on whether my intuition of what Quantum Mechanics "SHOULD" do is correct. And thats a pretty weak foundation in my opinion. I was hoping someone can give insight into a good ol' fashion linear algebraic proof of this.

Comment: Usually $f\otimes 1\circ 1\otimes g =(f\circ 1)\otimes (1\circ g)=f\otimes g =\cdots$, you get the idea. In fact you're checking that the tensor product is a bifunctor.

Comment: In general is $A \otimes B \circ C \otimes D = A \circ C \otimes B \circ D$? Assuming that $A \circ C$ and $B \circ D$ is well defined?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Perfect! If you don't mind could post these comments as an answer? Then I can accept it and that would give resolve to the question